# what does export {}; mean in a typescript.d.ts file

Tags: typescript

What does `export {}` mean in a typescript declaration (`.d.ts`) file.

I wrote some typescript and noticed that the generated `.d.ts` files might have a `export {};` at the end.
what does this mean in typescript?

Comment: does your code export anything? I'd guess it is just getting typescript to interpret it as a module which only happens if there is an import or export.

Comment: It already has exports. the `export {};` is at the end of the file

Comment: hmm, well `export {}` definitely shouldn't change any behaviour in a `ts` file if there are other exports but there are some odd legacy behaviours of declaration files that depends on the specifics of how declaration files are used, what specifically are you using to get the `.d.ts` files? straight `tsc` or babel? is your tsconfig small enough you could share it?

Answer (score 3):

It probably is too late to answer this but still, it might be useful for someone else afterwards.

I think your question is related to TypeScript's need for "export" or "import" clauses when declaring a module. Both keywords tell TypeScript the current file is a module and, thus, is allowed to provide certain functionalities such as using "while" outside of an async function. You can find more information on this section of the Top-level Await in TSlang.org documentation:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html

Comment: thanks all the same It might still be useful.... I never actually figured this out. I left typescript for a while. but I'll come back and look at this, Thanks.